Async start requests scrapy
Hi i wrote a code with scrapy it worked but when i change it to async code i getting this error


[    await process.crawl(WebSpider, start_urls=urls)

  File "/home/z/PycharmProjects/news-link-extractor/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1180, in send

    raise result.value

TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

And here is my code
`
class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = 'webspider'

 allowed_domains = allowed_domains



 custom_settings = {

     'RETRY_TIMES': 8,

     'RETRY_DELAY': 5,

     'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408],

 }



 @staticmethod

 async def get_start_urls():

     async with AsyncMySQLConnection() as mysql_connection:

         urls = await mysql_connection.select_urls(settings.DATABASE_NAME, settings.TABLE_NAME)

     return urls



 async def start_requests(self):

     urls = await self.get_start_urls()

     for url in urls:

         yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)



 async def parse(self, response):

     links = LinkExtractor(allowed_domains).extract_links(response)

     all_urls = [link.url for link in links]

     await URLManager().save_new_url_in_redis(all_urls)

     print(all_urls)

if name == 'main':
 from scrapy import cmdline, Request



 cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl webspider".split())`

I tried it  with ensureDeferred andinlineCllbacks and many way. it just work when write like this
start_request=[]

Nothing suggests you can use async def start_requests. You can't.

So what i have to do if my project need to be async?

Posted as an answer.

Until support for async def start_requests() is implemented in Scrapy, you can use the following workaround:
class MySpider(Spider):
    ...

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request("data:,", callback=self.parse_initial)

    async def parse_initial(response):
        ...  # produce the actual initial requests

    ...

This will allow you to use async code to get your initial requests ("data:," is an empty URL that doesn't cause any network requests).

Thanks for the reply,but I should get urls from database and all of  functions is async so if start requests isn't async i can not import any function from db in start requests

And the idea of this answer is to do that in the first callback, not in start_requests.

How? All link that i need to start my request is in db actually i don't know how do it without async or def start_requests

Have you read the answer you are commenting on?
